# Escape sequence getting error with my curl command in git bash

Tags: curl, git-bash

Hi am trying my curl command in git bash there is escape sequence error

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:8080/bimws/post/addCostCode -d '{""companyid"":""14"", ""costcodejson"":""{\""costcode\"":\""sample only\""}""}'
```

Answer (score 0):

"companyid": "129","costcodejson": "{\"costcode\":\"sample only\"}"